# Jquery Plugin Form no works fine

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

The Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#form1').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: processJson
  });
});

function processJson(data) {
  if (data.result == "ok") {
    $("#f1").show();
    var usernameValue = $('input[name=us]').fieldValue();
    alert("Nombre " + usernameValue);
  }
  //alert(data.result);
}
</script>
<script>
function test_form() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form2').ajaxForm({
      dataType: 'json',
      success: processJson2
    });
  });

  function processJson2(data) {
    if (data.result == "ok") {
      $("#f2").show();
      var usernameValue = $('input[name=us]').fieldValue();
      alert("Nombre " + usernameValue);
    }
    //alert(data.result);
  }
}
</script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="test_form.post.php" id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="us">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
<div id="f1" style="display:none;">Ejecutando Forma 1</div>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="test_form.post.php" id="form2">
  <input type="text" name="us">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" Onclick="test_form();">
</form>
<div id="f2" style="display:none;">Ejecutando Forma 2</div>
```

If you test , you can insert name in one field and push over the other form button and see the text insert in the other form and in the other case the same , no works for same fields under differents forms id , regards

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using a generic selector to retrieve you desired textbox.

When you apply the following:

```
$('input[name=us]').fieldValue()
```

you are retrieving the first-randomly selected textbox, because the

```
$('input[name=us]')
```

responds with two textboxes not one. It goes from the top of your documents and it searches for an input element with the name 'us'.
What you should do is sth like the following:

```
$("#form1").find("input[name='us']").val();
```

This is one of the many different ways you can do it..